# How to visual select from vimscript

Tags: vimscript, visual-mode

In Mac OS, I am trying to write a function that will say the current paragraph without moving the cursor, but something doesn't seem to work. This is what I have so far:

```
function! SayIt()
    let l:line = line(".")
    let l:col  = col(".")
    execute "normal V"
    execute "silent '<,'>w !say"
   call cursor(l:line,l:col)
endfunction

vnoremap <leader>v :call SayIt()<cr>
```

If I remove the `execute "normal V"` line the function works when I have previously selected a paragraph (or rather a long soft wrapped line). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the function doesn't work? What happens? Four things that occur to me: 1) you can only use the map from visual mode, because you create no mappings for other modes, 2) calling the function from visual mode, you may want to do `execute "normal V:!say"`, or else escape visual mode before the second `execute`, because in visual mode, `'<` moves to beginning of the _last_ visual selection, not the current, 3) `normal V` will select a line, not a paragraph–consider `vip`, and 4) the irony of `"silent ... !say"` ;)

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question, but I think Vim automatically puts the marks `'{` and `'}` around the current paragraph, so if you define the mapping `nnoremap <silent> <leader>v :<C-U>silent! '{,'}w !say<CR>` and hit `<leader>v` in normal mode, the contents of the current paragraph should be written on the standard input of the `say` program.

Comment: jjaderberg, you are right, one of the issues was the mapping. Yes, what an irony `silent ... !say`. saginaw, thank you very much. This solution worked great without the need of a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selection is being made with the `V` command, so your `'<,'>` marks are just set to that line.

Try to select the paragraph with the `ip` motion after going into visual mode, then the range will be what you want.

The `execute`s are unnecessary. Also that `cursor` stuff isn't the way the pros do it. :)

```
function! SayIt()
    let l:winview = winsaveview()
    normal Vip
    silent '<,'>w !say
    call winrestview(l:winview)
endfunction
```

Comment: Thank you. I keep learning great stuff here. This function works, but with some unexpected results. It seems to select, randomly the previous or the current paragraph.

Comment: Paragraphs are demarcated by blank lines, so if you have spaces on lines in between paragraphs they'll be treated as if there isn't a paragraph break. Otherwise I'm not familiar with what you're reporting, `ip` should select the containing paragraph if you're in one and the next paragraph if you aren't in one.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your help. In terms of functions, I think that the one posted by dash-tom-bang is the closest solution. But I have opted for the mapping suggested by saginaw.

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>v :<C-U>silent! '{,'}w !say<CR>
```

It works without the function.